# for_each C++ Problem

Tags: c++, foreach

I'm confused about the for each loop in C++. I have this code in a main game loop:

```
for each (Bubble b in bubbles){
    b.Update();
}
for each (Bubble b in bubbles){
    b.Draw();
}
```

It doesn't update anything, but does draw 1 bubble.. What's wrong with it?

EDIT: This code works

```
struct BubbleUpdater {
void operator()(Bubble & b) { b.Update(); }
} updater;
struct BubbleDrawer {
void operator()(Bubble & b) { b.Draw(); }
} drawer;

void OnTimer(){ //this is my main game loop
    std::for_each(bubbles.begin(),bubbles.end(),drawer);
    std::for_each(bubbles.begin(),bubbles.end(),updater);
}
```

Comment: `for each` is a syntax error. It shouldn't compile. Is this really what you have in your source file? Please copy and paste, don't retype from memory

Comment: What is `Bubble`? What framework are you using to write this game?

Comment: C++ does not natively have a "for each" construct. Are you using extensions from Qt by chance?

Comment: We'd need to see more code.  What is Bubble, what is expected in the Bubble::Update() function?  Are multiple threads executing (and possibly changing the bubbles container)?  Try a simple test of the `for each` with a `std::vector<int>` initialized with known values.  Does that work as you expect?

Comment: Do you mean C# instead of C++? And do you mean `foreach` instead of `for each`?

Comment: @bdonlan `for each` isn't part of any C++ standard, but it is a Microsoft specific extension supported (at least) since Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: This is my source code, it compiles and runs without error in Visual C++ 2010... Bubble is my own object, it just updates its position and draws itself

Comment: @CHad, ah, yes, looks like it's a managed C++ extension

Comment: @Cbas, for future reference, you're programming in managed C++, which, despite the name, is VERY different from C++. You'll get appropriate help a lot faster if you mention this at the start, as otherwise us C++ programmers will be terribly confused :)

Comment: Oh ok, sry I didn't know there was a difference, I'm used to C# and java

Comment: Before changing the tag, perhaps we should ask, is it your *intention* to program in managed-c++?  Or are you trying to program in proper c++ and just got mixed up?

Comment: Not sure actually, I'm just using the DragonFire SDK with Visual C++ to port a game to the iphone

Comment: `for each` will compile as non-managed C++ in Visual Studio 2010.  It's Microsoft specific syntaxic sugar that _should_ work in the same manner as `std::for_each` (with an appropriate functor) or `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure DragonFire SDK does not work with managed-c++, so I'm changing the tag back to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your BubbleUpdater class to accept it's argument by reference

```
struct BubbleUpdater {
void operator()(Bubble & b) { b.Update(); }
} updater;
```

With that, your call to `std::for_each` should work.

If your compiler supports it (and VC10 does), then you can use lambdas instead of creating a distant function object class.  And yes, it's standard c++, or will be soon enough.

```
std::for_each (bubbles.begin(), bubbles.end(), [](Bubble & b){
    b.Update();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well in C#, it drove me crazy for a while.  From what I found, the for each loop creates a new object for each object in your collection.  So it's creating something by value, rather than by reference (if you used a standard for loop), which results in the original collection not being effected.  I always found for each loops good for reading, but not for updating.

Answer (score 1):

`for each` isn't valid c++, and if you were thinking of `std::for_each()` or `BOOST_FOREACH` they have different syntax.

`std::for_each` is a function and has the following interface:

```
std::for_each(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, function f);
```

`BOOST_FOREACH` is a preprocessor macro and has the following interface:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(element e, container c)
{
do_thing(e);
e.whatever();
}
```

Comment: Ok, std::for_each isn't recognized and neither is BOOST_FOREACH. I have "using namespace std" at the top of my code - is there another extension I have to declare?

Comment: @cbas, std::for_each requires `#include <algorithm>`. BOOST_FOREACH requires that you install the boost library and `#include <boost/foreach.hpp>`

Comment: `std::for_each` is in the `<algorithm>` header file (use `#include <algorithm>`), and `BOOST_FOREACH` is part of the [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/)

Answer (score 1):

That's not C++, it's a Qt extension from memory. The new C++0x for each loop will have the syntax

```
for(type identifier : expression)
```

that is,

```
for(auto x : std::string("ohai"))
```

However, in C++03 there is no dedicated for each loop language construct.